# search MySQL and show result from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm have made a search function in PHP for my MySQL database. The search works but I want to display the result in a special way. I'm using cards to show the tables where some information is from the table (LessonPlans) I search and another information is from another table (Images). The original code was this:

```
<?php
require_once("db_link.inc.php");

if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $link->escape_string($_GET['search']);
    $query = $link->query("SELECT Subject, Level, Aim FROM LessonPlans WHERE Subject LIKE '%".$search."%' OR Level LIKE '%".$search."%' OR Aim LIKE '%".$search."%' AND Language='English'");

if($query->num_rows){
    while($r = $query->fetch_object()){

    echo '<div class="col s6 m4 l3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <img class="activator" src="../mlslp/assets/img/'. $r->Name-img .'" alt="'. $r->Alt-img .'">
                </div>
                <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 truncate tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="800" data-tooltip="'.$r->Subject.'">'.$r->Subject.'</span>
                    <p class="blue-text">'.$r->Level.'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a href="lessonplan.php?Id='. $r->Id .'">Open Lesson Plan</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">'.$r->Subject.'<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                    <p>'.$r->Aim.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

The tables I want to use are:

```
LessonPlans
Id | ImageId | Subject | Level | Aim | Language
```

and

```
Image
ImageId | Name-img | Alt-img
```

As it is it shows the correct result from LessonPlans but not the information that is not searchable. I know it will not work like this and I've tried with `UNION`, `JOIN` and as well with just two `SELECT` queries. As soon as I add the `Images` table into the query I get this error message:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ...
```

From what I understand, this is because `$query` is not an object when I add another table. What I don't understand is how I get around this. There must be a way to search one table but display results from two tables. Does anyone know how to do this?

What query do I need and how do I display it all?

Comment: where from you get this one $row["Name-img"] ?

Comment: This is what I want to print that is from `Images`. In my "normal" display I use `$sql_result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM LessonPlans l, Images i WHERE l.ImageId=i.ImageId AND l.Language='English' ORDER BY l.Id DESC;")` and ` while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result))` and then I display  with row["***"]. So I left it there to highlight that it's from the other table.

Comment: I updated with the correct $r->*** everywhere

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM LessonPlans AS L 
JOIN Image AS I 
ON L.ImageId=I.ImageId  
WHERE L.Subject 
LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR L.Level LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR L.Aim LIKE '%".$search."%' 
AND L.Language='English'
```

and ouput you get the output by $r =$query->fetch_object() so you have to use object to get the value like this **$r->Subject**

Comment: This doesn't help me displaying anything from `Images`

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

select table1.firstname, table2.lastname from table1, table2
    where table1.id = table2.id

Comment: That won't solve the problem of displaying from both tables